# How do you determine the way to write functions so that they are compatible for composing?

Tags: haskell

Let's say we have these 2 functions

```
f1 :: Int -> [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
f1 _ [] _ = []
f1 x (h:t) y = (x * h + y):(f1 x t y)

f2 :: [Int] -> Int
f2 (h:t) = h
```

Why does `(f2 . f1 1 [1..10]) 1` work, but `(f2 . f1 1) [1..10] 1` doesn't work?

Comment: `(f2 . f1 1) [1..10] 1` is equivalent to `f2 (f1 1 [1..10]) 1`

Comment: But f1 takes 3 parameters, so why aren't both the list and the int being applied to f1? Does it always stop at "taking" just 1 parameter?

Comment: `(f . g)` will only pass *one* parameter to `g`, `f . g` is equivalent to `\x -> f (g x)`, that's all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*All* functions in Haskell take exactly one argument and return one value. The argument and/or the return type could be another function.

`f1` has an argument type of `Int` and a return type of `[Int] -> Int -> [Int]`. The right associativity of `(->)` means we don't have to explicitly write this as

```
f1 :: Int -> ([Int] -> (Int -> [Int]))
```

but can instead drop the parentheses.

---

(Yes, `(->)` is an operator. You can use `:k` in GHCi to see the kind, but unfortunately what you get back is more complicated than we want to explain here:

```
> :k (->)
(->) :: TYPE q -> TYPE r -> *
```

Don't worry about what `TYPE q` and `TYPE r` stand for. Suffice it to say that `(->)` takes two types and returns a new type, and we can assume a simpler kind like

```
(->) :: * -> * -> *
```

The kind `*` is the kind of an ordinary type, more frequently written as `Type` these days.
)

---

In order to compose two functions, the return type of one must match the argument type of the other. We can see this from the type of `(.)` itself:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
        ^                ^
```

That's not the case with `f1` and `f2`:

```
--            vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
f1 :: Int -> ([Int] -> Int -> [Int])
f2 ::        [Int]                    -> Int
--           ^^^^^
-- [Int] -> Int -> [Int] and [Int] are different types
```

nor with `f1 1` and `f2`

```
--                vvvvvvvvvvvv
f1 1 :: [Int] -> (Int -> [Int])
f2   ::          [Int]           -> Int
--               ^^^^^
-- Int -> [Int] and [Int] are different types
```

but it *is* true of `f1 1 [1..10]` and `f2`:

```
--                     vvvvv
f1 1 [1..10] :: Int -> [Int]
f2           ::        [Int] -> Int
--                     ^^^^^
-- [Int] and [Int] are the same type
```

---

While `(->)` is right-associative, function application is *left*-associative, which is why we can write

```
((f1 1) [1..10]) 1
```

as `f1 1 [1..10] 1` instead, leading to the appearance of `f1` as taking 3 arguments, rather than an expression involving 3 separate function calls. You can see the three calls more clearly if you use a `let` expression to name each intermediate function explicitly:

```
let t1 = f1 1
    t2 = t1 [1..10]
    t3 = t2 1
in t3
```

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to chepner's excellent answer, here's a less formal way of looking at it (which might be more intuitive if you haven't assimilated the formalities yet).

You seem to be thinking of `(f . g) arg` as a special syntactic form that will pass the argument to `g` and then call `f` on the result<sup>1</sup>. In fact this isn't what happens (or at best it's a shorthand for what happens).

Remember that functions are first class in Haskell. Frequently when that is brought up it means that we are passing functions as values to other functions, or storing them in data structures. But here what we need to remember is that first-class values can be *computed* as the result of expressions. `f . g` is an expression that *computes* a new function, in precisely the same manner that `7 + 9` is an expression that computes a new integer.

So `(f . g) arg` is not passing `arg` to `g`. It's passing `arg` to the function that is computed by the expression `f . g`. And if we had multiple arguments where `arg` is written, as in `(f . g) x y z` they would **all** be passed to the whole function `f . g`. There is no way for any of them to be passed to `g` directly.

The `.` operator builds a new function out of `f` and `g` by producing a function that behaves as follows: it takes a single argument `x`, passes it to `g` and then passes the result of that to `f`. In Haskell syntax that is basically `(f . g) x = f (g x)`<sup>2</sup>. So if we try to pass multiple arguments, as in `(f . g) x y z`, we end up with this:

```
(f . g) x y z = (f (g x)) y z
```

You can see this doesn't end up passing more arguments to `g` before `g`'s result is fed to `f`; rather `y` and `z` end up being passed to the final result after `x` has been fed all the way through `g` *and* `f` (this is only going to work if `f` itself returns a function after being applied to one argument<sup>3</sup>). A simple way to think of it is that the *first* argument to the composed function "flows through the composition pipeline"; any other arguments will be passed to the *result*, after `x` has "flowed through". If we wanted the extra arguments to be passed to `g`, we should write it this way:

```
(f . g x y) z = f (g x y z)
```

Note that this reframes the "flow"; now it's **`z`** that is feeding through the composed functions. `x` and `y` have moved to being part of the *definition* of one of the two composed functions (`g x y` is every bit as much of an "expression that computes a function" as `f . g` is). If you really want the emphasis to be on `x` "flowing through" the composition pipeline, you'll need to change the way you defined `g` so that it takes arguments in a different order. This is a big part of why Haskellers frequently write functions to take the "main thing being operated on" as their *last* argument.

With all that in mind, your question should be pretty clear now.

In `(f2 . f1 1 [1..10]) 1` the outermost `1` will "flow through the pipeline"; the first stage of the pipeline is `f1 1 [1..10]` (so the `1` will end up as a third argument to `f1`).

Whereas in `(f2 . f1 1) [1..10] 1`, the `[1..10]` will "flow through the pipeline", and the outer `1` will only be passed to the final result of the whole pipeline, not to the first stage of the pipeline. And the final result of the composition pipeline is the result of `f2`, which is a simple `Int` and cannot be applied to more arguments.

---

<sup>1</sup> Haskell *does* have syntax for "pass multiple arguments to one function, then call another function on the result of that". However it's much more pedestrian. Just write `f (g x y z)`. If this looks simpler to you than trying to twist it into a chain of function compositions, then just write it directly.

---

<sup>2</sup> `(f . g) x = f (g x)` is *almost* the literal definition of the `.` operator. The real definition is `f . g = \x -> f (g x)`. This definition is equivalent in the sense that it always produces exactly the same result, but it is usually a bit more efficient.

---

<sup>3</sup> And your `f2` example does not return a function after being applied to one argument (it just returns an `Int`), so we can see that `(f2 . _anything_) arg1 arg2` is definitely going to be a type error with no further analysis, no matter what other function you're composing or what the two arguments are.